# How to merge touched paths in fabrcjs?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am developing a mobile application for drawing and I need to merge paths when they are touching each other, but they currently overlap one another. Is there any other way to do it?

In the below image I want to achieve the right side, not the left side.

What should I do? Below is my fabric.js code.

```
 setCanvasBackground(imagePath) {
      fabric.Image.fromURL(imagePath, (img)=>  {
         this.scaleAndPositionImage(img);
      });
      this.canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = this.brushColors[0];
      this.canvas.on('path:created', (opt) => {
        // opt.path.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
        this.canvas.renderAll(this.canvas);
      });
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Fabric.js currently has no inbuilt functionality for path boolean operations like add/subtract.

https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/4977

There is however fantastic support for boolean operations built into the paper.js library, so you could rely on paper.js for your path calculations and then bring the new path data back into your fabric canvas.

http://paperjs.org/examples/boolean-operations/